# Python -- Reading individual tokens in line

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file with raw data, but the catch is that it's all in one line in the file. I'm trying to read it into a 250X250 array with Python. How would I read in each floating-point token so that I can store every 250 tokens in one array (and then store those 250 arrays into another array)?

Here is a sample of the larger text file:

```
2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07
```

Comment: What code have you tried, and how does it come up short?

Comment: a quick fix would be to read it in and use [numpy.split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to generate array from the file and then reshape.

```
>>> x=np.genfromtxt('X.txt')
>>> x
array([ 0.26027502,  0.52344602,  0.94682873, ...,  0.18915237,
        0.12961926,  0.94742386])
>>> x.shape
(62500,)
>>> x = np.reshape(x, (250,250))
>>> x
array([[ 0.26027502,  0.52344602,  0.94682873, ...,  0.65515665,
         0.97133803,  0.82415501],
       [ 0.07134358,  0.71362599,  0.13989969, ...,  0.93441374,
         0.68241895,  0.60303783],
       [ 0.53491496,  0.39968921,  0.06248397, ...,  0.21473073,
         0.16831451,  0.31789734],
       ..., 
       [ 0.10877778,  0.06762419,  0.81900428, ...,  0.74856093,
         0.26248398,  0.22870396],
       [ 0.37090122,  0.8382394 ,  0.00154593, ...,  0.2041584 ,
         0.46904135,  0.03799747],
       [ 0.9419627 ,  0.72610034,  0.44279619, ...,  0.18915237,
         0.12961926,  0.94742386]])
>>> x.shape
(250, 250)
```

And of course you have an access for any row or column....

```
>>> x[0,:]
array([ 0.26027502,  0.52344602,  0.94682873,  0.10665757,  0.79377438,
        0.65801494,  0.58140499,  0.66640962,  0.43373581,  0.16128319,
        0.70266644,  0.01818846,  0.01782449,  0.32032342,  0.97500891,
        0.60327757,  0.59009519,  0.69106757,  0.94622942,  0.15136957,
        0.1287025 ,  0.19983005,  0.05298404,  0.92093835,  0.78505228,
        0.83958482,  0.07733883,  0.62988452,  0.6814386 ,  0.81682639,
        0.03053231,  0.05236924,  0.40785548,  0.16167756,  0.44625781,
        0.07929286,  0.21503215,  0.40479275,  0.45633735,  0.66524651,
        0.90779273,  0.866891  ,  0.94648979,  0.36298146,  0.93570324,
        0.07487549,  0.90450725,  0.41796693,  0.58045668,  0.47335179,
        0.6055467 ,  0.49201359,  0.84480727,  0.81318106,  0.60810966,
        0.23604474,  0.01072344,  0.11842985,  0.04188813,  0.36055357,
        0.94984941,  0.03620454,  0.34074396,  0.95193302,  0.91658527,
        0.73808885,  0.61518864,  0.43055782,  0.59904923,  0.14752041,
        0.20079651,  0.65231914,  0.98935973,  0.21159892,  0.5232117 ,
        0.96854742,  0.54765697,  0.74270461,  0.87702194,  0.86796058,
        0.03775362,  0.93498823,  0.68149649,  0.2642807 ,  0.37778898,
        0.26517663,  0.58759482,  0.02787823,  0.49535491,  0.2782437 ,
        0.98357993,  0.26340913,  0.24554617,  0.55307224,  0.22888235,
        0.81380607,  0.66314271,  0.40915715,  0.02140317,  0.96048781,
        0.82699845,  0.99421736,  0.25717857,  0.69675432,  0.4508669 ,
        0.71091636,  0.36017548,  0.2318293 ,  0.76682321,  0.73577509,
        0.89874027,  0.0409444 ,  0.16536175,  0.44526221,  0.60660233,
        0.45460512,  0.98345256,  0.3663255 ,  0.41726855,  0.96165547,
        0.64764743,  0.47367676,  0.85408071,  0.93389485,  0.31320421,
        0.40817909,  0.44824983,  0.405523  ,  0.21725864,  0.9549355 ,
        0.43012559,  0.69112666,  0.11570064,  0.09021077,  0.45238228,
        0.73020711,  0.96987082,  0.70582309,  0.2553982 ,  0.44727506,
        0.34449858,  0.76815233,  0.83751986,  0.85879128,  0.36974847,
        0.60779081,  0.38851576,  0.75236873,  0.02096765,  0.49170901,
        0.22284193,  0.24787976,  0.45656373,  0.25239485,  0.7795917 ,
        0.12916153,  0.48706096,  0.86036065,  0.51849597,  0.93765905,
        0.25232495,  0.62851966,  0.95089984,  0.63946114,  0.46297102,
        0.35535271,  0.58080051,  0.94821943,  0.9492573 ,  0.68737527,
        0.39894097,  0.6795753 ,  0.43546261,  0.82748096,  0.40663179,
        0.4553727 ,  0.48005262,  0.82583658,  0.99992761,  0.22148   ,
        0.65097962,  0.2815746 ,  0.17627066,  0.44245061,  0.26597802,
        0.38617241,  0.24852152,  0.50053587,  0.08652393,  0.84219587,
        0.39225673,  0.26653707,  0.54875435,  0.82991054,  0.89961175,
        0.41999139,  0.47578158,  0.72916822,  0.67832111,  0.35396472,
        0.29938162,  0.91833388,  0.37599509,  0.64598379,  0.46118518,
        0.82788677,  0.58454944,  0.09946118,  0.69875907,  0.69998759,
        0.3966504 ,  0.99769481,  0.80346738,  0.81667523,  0.21152416,
        0.28419954,  0.17771031,  0.23944737,  0.74009348,  0.22675329,
        0.37958291,  0.48378594,  0.77022399,  0.2577831 ,  0.84859331,
        0.76122995,  0.48038794,  0.80287582,  0.74552124,  0.38759297,
        0.65152917,  0.98425492,  0.14493465,  0.96483483,  0.6265678 ,
        0.1625753 ,  0.66836669,  0.61827808,  0.12794944,  0.8109776 ,
        0.6032338 ,  0.88499851,  0.59360774,  0.57160687,  0.22021264,
        0.39861853,  0.82982888,  0.65515665,  0.97133803,  0.82415501])
>>>
```

Comment: That works quite well! I'd been trying to do it with numpy, but I wasn't familiar with genfromtxt().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression module re

```
import re
lineArray = map(float, filter(None, re.split("\s", line)))
```

`lineArray` then contains all values as float.

Some background: the argument `"%s"` in split() tells the routine to divide the string at every whitespace (tab, linebreak, space..), `filter()` takes out empty strings, as they would occur when two consecutive whitespaces are found and `map(float, list)` applies float() to all elements of list.

Answer (score 0):

First you use regular expression to convert to array of floats and then slice the array to 250 arrays inside an array.

```
import re

one_line = map(float, filter(None, re.split("\s", s)))

def slice_per(array, slice_size):
    return [array[i::slice_size] for i in range(slice_size)]

arrayed_pic = slice_per(one_line, 250)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = "2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07 2.07"
list_of_flt_values = values.split()

array_of_list = []

size_of_each_list = 8
leng_of_flt_values = len(list_of_flt_values)

if size_of_each_list % 2 == 0 :
    number_of_list_blocks = int(leng_of_flt_values / size_of_each_list) 
else:
    number_of_list_blocks = int(leng_of_flt_values / size_of_each_list) + 1


for i in range(0, number_of_list_blocks):
    if (i + 1) * size_of_each_list > leng_of_flt_values:
        array_of_list.append(list(list_of_flt_values[i*size_of_each_list:]))
    else:
        array_of_list.append(list(list_of_flt_values[i*size_of_each_list:(i+1)*size_of_each_list]))


print array_of_list
```

I liked how [rth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42931284/3526330) approached the problem, If you want to do it from scratch you can try this

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and convert to floats using a list comprehension and then use `range` to generate indicies to split that into the final array. I'll demonstrate on a 10x10 array

```
>>> text = " ".join(str(float(i)) for i in range(100))
>>> floats = [float(s) for s in text.split(' ')]
>>> array = [floats[i:i+10] for i in range(0,100,10)]
>>> for l in array:
...     print(l)
... 
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
[10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0]
[20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0]
[30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0]
[40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0]
[50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0]
[60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0]
[70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0]
[80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 89.0]
[90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0, 99.0]
```